# Can't reinstall ubuntu 16.04, getting grub error

Tags: 16.04, grub2

My ubuntu installation started acting weird after I removed some packages (yes, my fault). I'm trying to reinstall it from the same USB I installed it in the first place. It's not working though. The error I'm getting is:

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.
```

How can I work this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are there any other systems on this machine? if not a possible solution might be to start the live session (aka "try ubuntu") open gparted and erase the whole disk, so the installer starts from a clean system

Answer (score 1):

Using boot-repair worked for me. Ubuntu is working now. Thank you all.